# Mathematical Paradox: How Can The Center of a Shape Be Located OUTSIDE This Shape?

Tags: geometry, centroid

Recently I have been learning about Geospatial Analysis in which we are often interested in using computer software to analyze the mathematical properties and characteristics of polygons (e.g. calculating their centroids).

For example, using the R programming language, I downloaded a geospatial file of Canada that is broken up into different "polygons" - I then attempted to calculate the centroids of each of these polygons and visualize the results.

Here the Code :

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(sf)
    library(data.table)
    library(rvest)
    library(leaflet)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(urltools)
    library(leaflet.extras)
    library(stringr)
    library(magrittr)
    
    
    # Download zip files
    url_1 <- "https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/alternative_alternatif.cfm?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=lada000b21a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20151162&loc=//www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/boundary-limites/files-fichiers/lada000b21a_e.zip"
    
    
    download.file(url_1, destfile = "lada000b21a_e.zip")
    
    # Extract zip files
    unzip("lada000b21a_e.zip")
    
    # Read shapefiles
    ada <- st_read("lada000b21a_e.shp")
    
    shapefile_1 = ada %>% st_transform(32617)
    #sf_cent <- st_centroid(shapefile_1)
    
    sf_cent <- st_point_on_surface(shapefile_1)
    
    # Transform the centroids to the WGS84 CRS
    sf_cent_geo <- st_transform(sf_cent, crs = 4326)
    
    
    # Extract the longitude and latitude coordinates of the centroids
    lon <- st_coordinates(sf_cent_geo)[,1]
    lat <- st_coordinates(sf_cent_geo)[,2]
    
    ADAUID <- sf_cent_geo$ADAUID
    lon <- st_coordinates(sf_cent_geo)[,1]
    lat <- st_coordinates(sf_cent_geo)[,2]
    
    shapefile_1 = ada %>% st_transform(32617)
    sf_cent <- st_centroid(ada)
    
    ggplot() + 
        geom_sf(data = shapefile_1, fill = 'white') +
        geom_sf(data = sf_cent, color = 'red')
```

The results look something like this:

[image: CENTROID]

**As we can see, some of these polygons appear to have multiple centroids ("red points") - this means the centroids for some of these polygons are located outside of these polygons themselves!**

Based on these two references here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid), the formula for calculating the centroid of a polygon can be written as such (based on the area of the polygon):

$$A = \frac{1}{2} | \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i) |$$

$$C_x = \frac{1}{6A} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} ((x_i + x_{i+1}) (x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i))$$

$$C_y = \frac{1}{6A} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} ((y_i + y_{i+1}) (x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i))$$

My Question: **Is it possible to mathematically prove that sometimes $C_x$ and $C_y$ can be located outside the perimeter of the polygon that they belong to? Otherwise, how else is it possible that the centroid of a polygon can be located outside of the polygon itself?**

Thanks!

Comment: The centroid of a boomerang is most certainly outside its body. The centroid is only guaranteed to be inside for *convex* shapes.

Comment: @ dvix: thank you so much for your reply! This is the first time I have ever heard about this result where a centroid is only guaranteed to be inside for convex shapes. do you recommend any references for this? if you have time, perhaps you could explain why this might is true? thank you so much!

Comment: Just think about a slightly thick letter "V."  Its centroid has to be along its midline by symmetry, and it can't be at the very bottom because that would place the whole letter above it.  Or think about a capital "U" with very thick arms and a very thin base.  Again, symmetry guarantees the centroid has to be in the gap between the arms.

Comment: @stats_noob Most basic property is that the centroid of a discrete set of points is a [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) of those points, and therefore lies within the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the points. This is why the midpoint of a segment is inside the segment, and the centroid of a triangle is inside the triangle. How you step from there up to infinitely many points and the continuous case depends  on the context and the "tools" you have available.

Comment: It seems to me you should start with a simpler set of data to see if your R code is any good. Especially if you are new at this, the chance that your output is simply wrong is high.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to answer the Question in the title & the last Sentences :
**"... Mathematically Prove that sometimes $C_x$ & $C_y$ can be located outside the Perimeter of the Polygon ..."**

**(1)** In a way , It is not Possible for $C_x$ & $C_y$ to be outside the **Zone** (range) of "Perimeter of the Polygon" , these are always within that **Zone**. This might be the Core Point of Confusion.
I am using the word "Zone" to keep it Intuitive , there are technical ways to put it with Mathematical terminology later.

Consider this Blue Polygon (more generally : Shape/area/region) with Centeroid @ $O$ :
[image: LIGHT BLUE POLYGON]

Then , $C_x$ , the x-Co-ordinate of $O$ , must be within the Gray lines.
More-over , $C_y$ , the y-Co-ordinate of $O$ , must be within the Purple lines.
In general , we can have Slanting Parallel lines (Eg the Green lines) touching the Polygon at the 2 Extremes , where we can say that $O$ & $C_x$ & $C_y$ must lie within those (Green) lines.
Thus , the Centeroid must lie within the "Zone".
Proving that is via Symmetry , Integration , linear Combinations , Etc.

**(2)** Must the Centeroid be a Part of the Polygon ? Not necessary ! It must be in the "Zone" but not necessarily within the Polygon !

**Example 2.1:**
Take the Earlier Image , Cut out a Part which has $O$ , then the Centeroid may move around a little , but it will be "outside" the area , though within the "Zone" !
[image: DARK BLUE POLYGON]
Here , I have Cut out a Small Hexagonal area , hence $O$ will lie "outside" the Blue area , maybe moving around a little.

**Example 2.2:**
Consider Squares & Circles , where the Centeroid is at the Exact "Center".
[image: Square Circle]

We can cut out a smaller similar area at the Center , then the Centroid is outside , though still at the "Center". We can then cut out the Purple Part , which will make the top lighter , the bottom heavier , hence $C_y$ will move downward. It makes the left lighter, the right heavier , hence $C_x$ will move a little right.
We can then cut out the Green Part , which make the top lighter , hence $C_y$ moves downwards. It makes the left & right Equal weight , hence $C_x$ goes back.
With a large enough cut-out (Eg at the Dotted lines) , we can make the Centroid move downward back into the Blue area.

**(3)** Mathematically , we can state it like this :
In all these Cases , $O$ can not occur outside the "Zone" :
$x_{min} \le C_x \le x_{max}$
$y_{max} \ge C_y \ge y_{min}$
In other words , we take the whole Polygon / area / region & take the minimum values & maximum values of $x$ & $y$ , then we know where the Centeroid must occur. The Exact values can be computed using various formulas.
Without knowing the Exact Polygon , we might make quick inaccurate approximations like $C_x = [ x_{min} + x_{max} ] / 2$ & $C_y = [ y_{max} + y_{min} ] / 2$ , though that is very rarely the Case.

Comment: @ prem: thank you so much for your detailed answer! I really appreciate it!

Comment: More generally, the centroid of a shape in $\mathbb{R}^n$ always lies in its convex hull. @stats_noob